# Linked lists: auto-create items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, power-automate, flow

We need to split up information into multiple list, which are then linked in on "master list".

[image: sample image]

*(sample image from internet)*

In the sample our master list is "Orders", "Ordered Books" is connected via a lookup column.

How can I manage, that when a new item in **Orders** is created, there's automatically a new item in **Ordered Books** which is directly linked to the initial item?

Is Power Automate required or can I manage this within SharePoint/Lists itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need a Power automate flow to create a new item in "Ordered Books" list automatically.

Follow this:

1. Create a Power automate flow on "Orders" list using "When an item is created" trigger.
2. Add "Create item" action to create a new item in "Ordered Books" list.
3. You can use "ID" (item ID) from dynamic content from trigger output to update the lookup column in "Ordered Books" list. You can use other column values as well from trigger output as per your requirements.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/)

Comment: Hi @Der_Fab, does this help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.